# Is Scala too complex for any IDE to support refactoring equivalent to refactoring support for Java / C#?

Tags: scala, automated-refactoring

The feature list of Scala IDE on typesafe.com touts basic refactoring support like rename, extract method, etc.  However I found the support to be quite abysmal. It breaks down quite easily and I find it is detrimental to its usability on a large scale project.

At a project we're going full on with scala and the lack of tooling is probably the hardest sell to Java and C# developers working in Scala.  It's hard to convince people to be excited about writing code, when rename is still not working properly.  Some people suggest Scala is too complex.  A claim that was originally made by Jetbrains at some point on the Kotlin FAQ on their website and seems to be prevalent.

Is there something to this claim?  Has typesafe just not being able to resource this functionality adequately until this point?

Comment: Scala-user mailing list will probably be a better place for this discussion.

Comment: you may want to have a look at intellij the community edition is free and supports the scala plugin. I find the support to be better than scala ide even though I miss the newly added worksheet

Comment: Typesafe didn't even exist until a few months ago; they now have multiple people working on it. Don't forget that this is free software; in a commercial environment you should consider paying for intellij, which is currently more mature.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge strictly speaking typesafe was founded [more than a year ago](http://typesafe.com/company/news/13822)

Comment: I've been programming in Scala using JetBrains IDEA with their Scala plugin and most of the refactorings just work. The plugin is still in development, which means that every now and then something breaks - but that's the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: If it's good enough for Odersky, it's good enough for me.

Comment: It isn't too complex.  It's just not done yet.  It's not as easy as with Java.